# Switch views from a different view Objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I'm using MFSideMenu to make a facebook style slide out menu. I'm trying to get it so when i click on a certain cell within the menu slideout, it switches to a specific view...

My problem is, how do i set the initial view to switch to the new view, rather than the menu view itself...

Obviously, using the code below will change this view, and i need to be able to change another view, called HomeViewController to another view...

```
[self presentModalViewController:viewControllerNameHere animated:YES];
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Anyone? Really need some help!

Comment: I'm not following what you're trying to achieve. When you say "switch to a specific view", what does that mean exactly? What's on the screen before the switch, and after?

Comment: Well, when i click on a cell in the slideout menu, i want a view to show on the screen. I dont want the menu view to change, i want a new view instead of the current view...

Comment: Stil stuck! Any help appreciated...

Comment: Basically, you need a controller class that interfaces with all of the views you are attempting to manage. Would you be able to provide some screenshots, or even simple drawings of your layout? If you like, google for "web whiteboard", draw your layout there, and grab a screenshot.

Comment: I'm not allowed to post images cause of my reputation, but i have 3 views, each have .h, .m, and .xib. In my menu view, in the implmentation file, in my didselectrow method its currently switching the menu view, the one that slides out like facebook, rather than the main view you see when the menu is closed. Thanks.

Comment: Before you call [self presentModalViewController:viewControllerNameHere animated:YES], you should do something like [viewControllerNameHere setOriginatingViewController:self]. Now you have a two-way connection between these view controllers and you can implement and call methods from one side to the other. Does this make sense? Does it help you solve the problem?